# visio - uml class diagram - show attribute comment & operation comment

Tags: uml, visio

I'm current work with VISIO UML diagram & I need to show comment on attributes and operations, GOOGLE for a times and can't find anything helpful so I post question here! 
any idea to make VISIO show comment on UML class diagram ?
as screen shot, my visio just can show header ,but I need to show comment like I could do with 
 Excel.
[image: excel]
[image: visio]